# factors <in/of> agricultural land degradation

Tags: prepositions

In the dictionary, the example sentences for the definition 'one of the elements contributing to a particular result' all use 'factor **in**'. However, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=factors%20of%20land%20degradation%2Cfactors%20in%20land%20degradation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows "factors **of** land degradation" is more common than "factors **in** land degradation". I wonder why? should I use "in" or "of"?

> Over-grazing, deforestation, and over-cultivation are the key factors
> **in/of** agricultural land degradation worldwide.

I wrote the sentence.

[image]

Comment: Just google it and see how serious the results are for: factors **in** land degradation. ngram will not answer this kind of question.

Comment: Your Ngram doesn't actually produce any results to compare the usage.